# Getting dynamic Image width

Tags: javascript, jquery

While i am trying to get the size of image so, that i can append same size of div to explain the image. Images are coming dynamically so how can i get the image size that appear on browser not the real size of image. I have tried following code but does not work when parent class is smaller the image.

```
$('img').each(function(i) {
  $currentImg = $(this);
  imgTextshow = $currentImg.attr('imgtext');
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    $currentImg.after("<div class='img-fscreen' style='width:" + this.width + "px; max-width:" + $currentImgParent + "'>" + imgTextshow + "</div>");
  }
  img.src = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Comment: Try using - `this.naturalWidth`

Comment: @vikrantsingh, OP is asking about the width of the image element after browser renders it..

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following lines of code inside of the onload handler, they should give you the correct dimensions:

```
$currentImg.width();
$currentImg.height();
```

simply because those methods return the width/height of the img DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below line

```
img.onload = function() {
   $currentImg.after("<div class='img-fscreen' style='width:" +  $currentImg.width() + "px; max-width:" + $currentImgParent + "'>" +    imgTextshow + "</div>");
}
```